# Ошибка при распаковке данных из БД

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть БД с данными о пользователях. Данные принимаю через цикл `for`:

```
        import sqlite3

        Connect = sqlite3.connect('TheTruckerDB.db')
        Cursor = Connect.cursor()

        user_id = event.object.from_id
        vk = session_api

        SQLCheck = """SELECT uid, fname, lname, car, money, lvl FROM Players WHERE uid = ?"""
        Cursor.execute(SQLCheck, (str(user_id),))

        for u_id, f_name, c, m, l in Cursor.fetchall():

                mess = '‍♂ Ваш профиль:\n\n:\t{u_id}\nИмя:\t{f_name}\nУровень:\t{l}\nТранспорт:\t{c}\nДенежный баланс:\t{m}\n\nДата регистрации:'

        send_message(vk, peer_id, message=mess)
```

При запросе, чтобы вывести данные через `send_message`. Но возникает ошибка:

```
   for u_id, f_name, c, m, l in Cursor.fetchall():
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)
```

Подскажите, что не так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш запрос выбирает из базы шесть полей для строки (uid, fname, lname, car, money, lvl).

А вот здесь:

```
for u_id, f_name, c, m, l in Cursor.fetchall():
```

Вы пытаетесь эти шесть значений распихать в пять переменных.

Соответственно, либо уберите из SELECT лишнее поле, либо добавьте в for ещё одну переменную.